# Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Face

Tags: c#, .net, распознавание-образов

Можно ли как-то получить рисунок по `PersistedFacesID`?

```
var faces = await client.DetectAsync(File.OpenRead(path));

var similarity = await client.FindSimilarAsync(faces[0].FaceId,"bp",FindSimilarMatchMode.matchFace);
```

А как дальше получить картинку по `PersistedFacesID`?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: прастите добавил